# Ignore empty textboxes while searching in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, search

This code is able to search and load data to `DataGridView` based on values provided in search form text boxes. If I left any text box blank, there is no search result since the SQL query is combined with "AND".

How can I ignore the empty textboxes while searching (from SQL query or C# code)?

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    String select = "SELECT DocumentNo, Revision, DocumentTitle, DocumentType
                     FROM DocumentLog
                     WHERE DocumentNo Like '%" + tbxDocumentNo.Text + "%'
                       AND Revision Like '%" + tbxRevision.Text + "%'
                       AND DocumentTitle Like '%" + tbxDocumentTitle.Text + "%'
                       AND DocumentType '%" + tbxDocumentType.Text + "%'"
                       AND IsDeleted = '0';

    SqlConnection conn = DBConnection.openConnection();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(select, conn);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    da.Fill(ds, "DocumentLog");

    dgvTracking.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgvTracking.DataSource = ds.Tables["DocumentLog"];
}
```

Comment: Please use bind parameters, your code is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

Comment: Why is line `AND IsDeleted = '0'` outside your query string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- First of all you have to replace the concatenated string queries with parameterized queries to avoid injection,
- Secondly you can use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` to check whether the value is null or empty before add them to the where clause.
- Third thing you need to notice is the multiple condition separator that is `AND`, if you add then In the beginning of the second condition (`tbxRevision`) then the query became error if `tbxDocumentNo` is null or empty. similar in the case of last if the last condition is false then query will ends up with an `AND` which is also an error, To avoid these we can take `IsDeleted='0'` as first condition in where as like i did in the following code,

please take a look:

```
string querySQL = "Select DocumentNo , Revision, DocumentTitle, DocumentType FROM DocumentLog WHERE IsDeleted='0'";
using(SqlConnection conSQL = DBConnection.openConnection())
{
    using(SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand())
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxDocumentNo.Text))
        {
            querySQL += "AND  DocumentNo Like @DocumentNo";
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@DocumentNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + tbxDocumentNo.Text + "%";
        }

        // Add rest of conditions here like this

        cmdSQL.CommandText=querySQL;
        cmdSQL.Connection = conSQL;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);                                     
    }
}
```

Comment: You can cheat and use the always hardcoded IsDeleted=0 instead of 1=1 :)

Comment: @nvoigt: thanks, you are right, I missed that condition; anyway I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your SQL command to include the clause `AND Revision Like ''` you will need to stop hardcoding your SQL command as a single string and instead build that string depending on your input boxes.

```
StringBuilder sqlCommandText = new StringBuilder();

sqlCommandText.Append("Select DocumentNo , Revision, DocumentTitle, DocumentType FROM DocumentLog WHERE IsDeleted = 0");

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxRevision.Text))
{
    sqlCommandText.Append(" AND Revision Like @revision");
    command.Parameters.Add("@revision", tbxRevision.Text);
}

// do this for all fields

command.CommandText = sqlCommandText.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use some query logic for this, for example the query could be:

```
Select DocumentNo , Revision, DocumentTitle, DocumentType 
FROM DocumentLog 
WHERE (DocumentNo Like '%"+tbxDocumentNo.Text+"%' OR tbxDocumentNo.Text = '') AND
(Revision Like '%"+tbxRevision.Text+"%' OR Revision = '') AND 
(DocumentTitle Like '%"+tbxDocumentTitle.Text+"%' OR DocumentTitle = '') AND
DocumentType '%"+tbxDocumentType.Text+"%'";AND IsDeleted='0'
```

Comment: I don't see how this is helping? The OP wants to omit the clause for a field when the value for a field was not given.