# How to disregard empty textbox or combobox in SQL SELECT?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a C# form that have a 6 filters (5 combobox, and 1 textbox) that the user can use to perform a search. The problem is that the user can leave some as blank or to use it all. To have a filtered search I used AND when doing a SELECT query, but the problem is it will return a blank or empty search when some of the filters is/are blank. If I will make each condition a query, I will have around 700 and so query. So I have search the closet, I think, scenario in this link

[Ignore empty textboxes while searching in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478585/ignore-empty-textboxes-while-searching-in-database)

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);
                                               Initial Catalog=inventory;
                                               Integrated Security=True"))
{
    conn.Open();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[product] WHERE IsDeleted = '0'";
    using (SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbItem.Text))
        {
            query += " AND Item Like @Item";
            scmd.Parameters.Add("@Item", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + item + "%";
        }
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbBrand.Text))
        {
        query += " AND Brand Like @Brand";
        scmd.Parameters.Add("@Brand", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + brand + "%";
        }
        //...additional query        
    }
    scmd.CommandText = query;
    scmd.Connection = conn;
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd))
    {
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

And when performing the search, it is having an error like this;

> 'Invalid column name 'IsNull'.'

My original query goes something like this. But this will select nothing if one of the where condition is blank/empty.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[product] WHERE Item = '" + item + "' 
                                AND Brand =  '" + brand + "'
                                AND Description = '" +desc + "'
                                AND Manufacturer = '" + manu + "'
                                AND Car = '" + car + "'
                                AND Year = '" + year + "'
```

If I use OR instead of AND. It will select something like this.

[OR Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc4Un.jpg)

[OR Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBYgA.jpg)

Below are the images for an ideal search.

[Image for ideal selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEpIS.jpg)

[Image for ideal selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUivB.jpg)

Solved, by changing IsDeleted='0' to 1=1

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM[dbo].[product] WHERE 1=1";
```

Comment: what is `item`  and `brand`, why don't you send `cmbItem.Text` and `cmbBrand.Text` in your query

Comment: check `query` value before executing command and find out why IsNull is there. most likely "//...additional query" part is wrong

Comment: @ASh //...additional query part is like if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(.. statement. but for other filter for dsecription, manufacturer, car, year. I just posted the first two to shorten it.

Comment: @styx item and brand are strings that get the value of the cmbItem and cmbBrand texts

Comment: @Jepher and when you try to do the original select(in your app ) you get the values as you want?

Comment: @styx if there are any blank parameters, it will show nothing. the user must fill up all the parameters. if i use OR instead of AND, it will show everything that match with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you can use store procedure and set parameter to default value

sample:

```
 create proc sptest
     @Fname nvarchar(50),
     @Lname nvarchar(50),
     @NCode nvarchar(12),
     @UserType int
     as

     SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,
                   FName,
                   LName,
                   NationalID,
                   UserType
            FROM   Persons 

            WHERE  
                    (FName LIKE('%' + @Fname + '%') OR (@Fname = ''))
                   AND (LName LIKE('%' + @Lname + '%') OR (@Lname = ''))
                   AND ((NCode = @NCode) OR (@NCode = ''))
                   AND ((UserType = @UserType) OR (@UserType = 0))
```

when textbox is empty or dropdownlists not is selected, get all record

Answer (score 0):

Your original if/and conditions should work, but what you might be running into is a false resolution of the table COLUMN vs the PARAMETER.  Since you have the example of

```
Item like @Item
```

if there is no actual parameter Item, SQL is implying to use its own value.  For these types of queries, I try to prefix the parameter name to match.  Change to

```
Item like @parmItem
```

and obviously change your parameter name string to match the "@parmItem" reference.  This way there is no ambiguity in what value the SQL engine is looking for.

Comment: the problem is it throws an error 'Invalid column name 'IsDeleted'.'

Comment: @Jepher, is the "IsDeleted" column a character or numeric.  If numeric flag, change '0' to remove quotes just IsDeleted = 0

Comment: still the same problem. i have solved it by substituting 1=1.